# Nextjs error occurred prerendering page "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error:

You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

```
./src/app/page.js
Attempted import error: 'Navbar' is not exported from './components/navbar' (imported as 'Navbar').

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.js

./src/app/page.js
Attempted import error: 'Navbar' is not exported from './components/navbar' (imported as 'Navbar').

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/page.js

info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Collecting page data
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\jasmi\OneDrive\Desktop\BoxingApp\boxingtrainer\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\jasmi\OneDrive\Desktop\BoxingApp\boxingtrainer\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\jasmi\OneDrive\Desktop\BoxingApp\boxingtrainer\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\jasmi\OneDrive\Desktop\BoxingApp\boxingtrainer\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
info  - Generating static pages (5/5)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /page: /
```

This happens when I try to run the command `npm run build` on a nextjs app I just started building. This is the code I have in `page.js`:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import { Navbar } from './components/navbar'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <Navbar/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

And in navbar:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav
      className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-10 bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-300"
      onMouseEnter={() => setShowNav(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShowNav(false)}
    >
      <div className="flex items-center h-full">
        <div className="ml-4 font-bold">Boxing Trainer</div>
        {loggedIn && (
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-1">
            <div className="w-6 h-6 mr-2 bg-gray-300 rounded-full"></div>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="flex items-center justify-end flex-1">
          {!loggedIn && (
            <>
              <button className="px-4 py-2 mr-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 border border-blue-500 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-50">
                Login
              </button>
              <button className="px-4 py-2 mr-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 border border-blue-500 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-50">
                Signup
              </button>
            </>
          )}
          {loggedIn && (
            <button className="px-4 py-2 mr-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 border border-blue-500 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-50">
              Logout
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not exporting the component in Navbar, only declaring it.

```
// Add this to the bottom of the file.
export {Navbar};
```

Comment: I'm updating my question to reflect having tried this solution. I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Emm I didn't see your page.js, so I didn't know that you are actually using a named import. Either you need to import it using a default import, or you can export it using a named import. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Emm tl;dr, just remove default after the export in navbar

Comment: Sorry, I've rewritten my answer because I was mistaken, but removing the `export default` and just adding the code in my answer should work.